# How do I get maximum supported CPU frequency on Mac M1?

Tags: c++, cpu-usage, apple-m1

On x86_64 I can get maximum CPU frequency with `__get_cpuid()`, but `cpuid.h` is unavailable on arm64. Is there a way to programmatically get maximum supported CPU frequency on Mac M1 processor from C++ or from command line?

Comment: This might be an XY problem.  Why do you think you need this information?

Comment: @NateEldredge I want to collect user's hardware information. So this is one of the pieces of that information.